# How to unescape XML in Qt?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have `QString` like `"&lt; foo &amp; blah &gt;"` (no tags, only character data) and I want to unescape it. There is `Qt::escape` function in `Qt` namespace, yet no reverse counterpart for it.

So, how can I unescape XML string in Qt?

Specific requirement: it must be possible with Qt 4.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone [made an html entity decoder in an answer to an old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082191/1084754). If you don't mind introducing a new dependency, that might be a good solution.