# How to unescape a string in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, urlencode

I have the following example:

```
%3ca href%3d%22http://google.com%22%3eGoogle%3c/a%3e
```

When unescaped I expect this to be:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

I've tried:

```
strUnescaped = QString::fromUtf8(strEncoded.toLatin1().data());
```

But the result is the same as the original unaffected and unmodified. What do I need to do?

Comment: @Jarod42, thank you, it didn't work, I tried:  QUrl::fromEncoded(strEncoded.toLatin1()).toString();  and the result was an empty string.

Comment: `QUrl::fromEncoded` will decode [URLs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#ParsingMode-enum) not escaped HTML. There are functions to escape but I don't see functions to unescape : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14173350/6165833

Comment: @ymoreau, thank you, bit unusual and a bit of a gap in the development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unescape XML in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513992/how-to-unescape-xml-in-qt)

Comment: @ymoreau, I saw that, however I was hoping there was a built in solution as part of the Qt library.

Comment: This might be better solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696159/how-can-i-convert-entity-characterescape-character-to-html-in-qt

Comment: @ymoreau, at the same time I found:  https://deepugeorge2007.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/decode-html-entities-in-qt/  I am trying this now.

Comment: @ymoreau, didn't work, result is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might use [`QUrl::fromPercentEncoding`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromPercentEncoding) to decode percent to regular character:

```
QString encodedStr = "%3ca href='http://google.com'%3eGoogle%3c/a%3e";
auto decodedStr = QUrl::fromPercentEncoding(encodedStr.toLatin1());
// decodedStr == "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>"
```

Comment: Thank you , trying now

Comment: How to make &lt; to <?

Comment: @Zhang: [how-can-i-convert-entity-characterescape-character-to-html-in-qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696159/how-can-i-convert-entity-characterescape-character-to-html-in-qt).

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks a lot!